# Check if an input date is older than x amount of days

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to find a way to validate if an input date chosen by the user, is older than the current date - 10 days. However, I'm stuck on this bit of code.

```
var date = document.getElementById("deliveryDate").value;
var varDate = new Date(date); 
var today = new Date();

if(varDate < today.setDate(today.getDate() - 10)) {
    alert("works!");
}
```

Comment: Dates are hard in JS. I suggest the use of https://date-fns.org/

Comment: Is the 10 days, 24hrs * 10 from current time, or start of day..?

Comment: Date inputs return the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, which is parsed as UTC with the time set to 00:00:00 UTC also. `new Date()` includes the current time. I don't see where you've taken those factors into account.